# Kibana regex not work

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I need to search for a range value from my logs, but my regex doesn't work in Kibana.

```
/(took":[1-9][0-9][0-9][,])/g
```

Content:

```
{"real_time":"2016-05-03T10:02:13.360Z","content":{"delay":687,"updated":true,"searchItems":{"monitoring_id":"111354","params":{"pass":["111354"],"named":{"d":"2016-04-29|2016-04-30"},"action":"mentions","plugin":null,"controller":"api11","form":[],"url":{"url":"1.1\/mentions\/111354\/","publickey":"yn68FDuQ","time":"1462303544,8356","signature":"102ade1f6749e89be876fdb00a7b9ade","published_date":"2016-04-29|2016-04-30","ipp":"100","page":"14"},"isAjax":false},"source_ids":"","timestamp":"","pagination":"1300, 100","trackerId":"","onlyIds":[],"exceptIds":[],"timezone":"Brazil\/East"},"search":[{"index":"mentions_ro","type":"mention","from":1300,"size":100,"body":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"monitoring.id":"111354"}},{"range":{"published_at":{"gte":"1969-12-31T21:00:00-03:00","lte":"1969-12-31T21:00:00-03:00"}}}]}},"sort":{"published_at":{"order":"desc"}}},"fields":[]}],"response":{"took":500,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":21,"successful":21,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}}}
```

My regex is working here, however:

https://regex101.com/r/pV4mR7/1

**Obs:**

- I already tried to escape some characters
- If I look the request sent to Elastic, Kibana uses a query string:

[image]

Any tips?

Comment: Just parse the JSON.  No need for regex here.

Comment: You can use something like `took:[100-999]` as a range filter.

Comment: My content is a string , not a json file

Comment: @Makoto i need the regex, this is a log and i can't change this now!

Answer (score 3):

According to their [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax) these characters are always metacharacters, and must be escaped if you want them as literals:

```
. ? + * | { } [ ] ( ) " \
```

These characters are metacharacters under certain modes:

```
@ & < >  ~ #
```

You don't need to put the comma in a char class.

It looks like you might not be able to just throw the regex in the search box.

> Kibana only matches regexp over the `_all` field:
>
> Try to "inspect" one of the elements in your page, you will see that `_all` field is hardcoded :
>
> ```
> "global": true,
>  "facet_filter": {
>    "fquery": {
>      "query": {
>        "filtered": {
>          "query": {
>            "regexp": {
>              "_all": {
>                "value": "category: /pattern/"
> ```
>
> > https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/631

Try this:

```
(took\":[1-9][0-9][0-9],)
```

I'm not familiar with Elasticsearch or Kibana, but your query may end up looking like this:

```
"regexp": {
 "_all": {
  "value": "category: /(took\":[1-9][0-9][0-9],)/"
 }
}
```

Comment: I escape [ and ], to fix parser error , and the search return no results!

Comment: @JoeLoco I have updated my post. I am not familiar with things, but I hope you recognize the syntax that they seem to suggest should be used.

Comment: Can you help me with that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939345/elastic-search-cant-find-the-results-from-regex-pattern