# Elastic Search can't find the results from Regex pattern

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I am searching a particular regex pattern in the Discover tab in Kibana through KQL and Lucence but I got

> error Expected ":", "<", "<=", ">", ">=", AND, OR, end of input,
> whitespace but "\" found.

I am trying to match that pattern  | 500 |

```
log:"api.mydomain.com" AND '\s5..\s'
 ----------------------------^
```

Here is the query I want to search **log: "api.mydomain.com" AND ' \s5..\s'**

How to do that?

Comment: Try escaping backslash:  `\\s` instead of `\s`

Comment: @Laurel I believe regex is not applying. It doest matches the pattern